# How to force div width with CSS to stretch to its content but not to be restricted by its container?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a HTML "showcase". I am thinking of using elements like this:

```
<div id="index-showcase-tabs">
    <div id="index-showcase-tabslide">                    
        <div class="index-showcase-tab" id="showcase-tab-1">Item1</div>
        <div class="index-showcase-tab" id="showcase-tab-2">Item2</div>
        ...
        <div class="index-showcase-tab" id="showcase-tab-N">ItemN</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The showcase items are floated left, and I don't know their precise width, nor the number of them.
Problem is: if the combined width of the items is bigger than the container (`index-showcase-tabs`), I don't want them to break line (which they do by default). I want them in one line, and I want to hide the overflow and then let the user scroll them with javascript (not by scrollbar...).

How would I do that?

PS: There's not much css for the items yet. I only gave the slider a specific heigth:

```
#index-showcase-tabslide
{
    height: 34px;
}
```

**Edit:** [Here you can see my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TbSfj/12/). 
**Edit2:** explaining more with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TbSfj/19/

Comment: That appears to be a list. You may want to use the UL element for that.

Comment: UL doesn't make any difference. They still break the line. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out this sexy control:

http://jsfiddle.net/SoonDead/U6QdQ/20/

this way made for my project, but I think it does what you want.

The tricks are:

Because you use a lot of characters that can "linebreak" and even forcefully disable linebreaks have different results in 1-2 browsers, I would recommend against it.

Instead make the overflowing width wide enough to hold all the elements easily, so if javascript is disabled it will not look ugly.

(I know that you are fine with jquery, so I use it within the example, also the outerWidth property in simple js has bugs in webkit (tends to be 0 in some cases).)

So you need to sum up the elements' outerWidth() and set the content holder's width, so you can use scrollLeft, and not overscroll.

There is no other trick, just a scrollTo function because calculating positions are not that trivial if you are new to jquery and you might want to use that.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you cannot use `float: left`. Instead use `display: inline` - this will have the same effect for what you want to accomplish, and it will not be constrained to the parent div in the DOM model.

Comment: Well, it certainly changed the picture, but there's still a linebreak, only now it "broke" one of the `index-showcase-tab` elements at a whitespace character. Is there something else I should set? Maybe on the container?

Comment: Try setting overflow: hidden on the wrapper

Comment: Created a JSFiddle (link at the end of the post). Added the `display: inline` as you suggested. The red div still stays inside the yellow one, thus breaking the line...

Comment: Okay, then here's another one based on yours, explaining more about the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/TbSfj/19/
See, I need the items to ACTUALLY stay in one line. Because of the scrolling.